# How to make wide tables responsive on mobile devices using CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my predicament. I am updating a really old site that someone else developed to use responsive design. One page has a table with code like below. The table spans too wide for mobile, and basically what I need is for the second cell to display below the first one. Is there a way to do this in CSS? I would like to not touch the HTML if at all possible.

```
<table style="margin-top: 15px;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 20px;">
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible in CSS alone; you'll need a bit of Javascript to help you. Fortunately there are several decent Javascript plugins around which offer a lot of flexibility.

CSS-Tricks has a good [roundup](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/). Personally I like [Tablesaw](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw) from Filament Group. All you need to do is to link their javascript and then add the appropriate attributes to your table to get the functionality you want (because it offers quite a lot of options).

Alternatively I like [Zurb's plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables) for a simple and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tables doesn't collpase like responsive grids. If you decide to use responsive framwork. You can get more information from link below:

[bootstrap/responsive-tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)